# A sufficient condition for irreducibility of a polynomial in an extension field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Here is another problem of the book *Fields and Galois Theory* by Patrick Morandi, page 37.

> Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial over $F$ of degree $n$, and let $K$ be a field extension of $F$ with $[K:F]=m$. If $\gcd(n,m)=1$, show that $f$ is irreducible over $K$.

I'm preparing for my midterm exam so I'm trying to solve as many as this book problems. Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $L \supset K$ be obtained by adjoining a root of $f$ to $K$, say $\alpha$. Then consider the chains $F \subset K \subset L$ and $F \subset F(\alpha) \subset L$. You know $[F(\alpha):F] = n$, because $f$ is irreducible over $F$. What does this tell you about $[L:K]$?

Comment: Are you reasoning for the absurd ?, are you assuming that $f$ is reducible over $K$ and so there exists such a $\alpha$? Or as? Why does this $\alpha$ exist?

Comment: @Nash Let $g$ be an irreducible factor of $f$, and let $L := K[x]/g(x)$. Then $L = K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the image of $x$ in $L$.

Comment: That's in answer to why $\alpha$ exists. As for what my reasoning is here, I'm just alluding to some basic divisibility theorems of chains of extensions.